# Event bubbling in jQuery - event.stopPropogation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to prevent a click form bubbling to the parent `<a>` HTML tag. Here is my code:

```
var $result = $("<a href='" + result["link"] + "' class='list-group-item'></a>");
var $title = $("<h4 class='list-group-item-heading'>" + result['title'] + "</h4>");
var $snippet = $("<p class='list-group-item-text'>" + result['htmlSnippet'] + "</p>");

// some code omitted for brevity

var $expandBooksbutton = $("<button type='button' id='btn-showMoreBooks' class='btn btn-default btn-xs'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-resize-full'></span> expand</div></button>");

$expandBooksbutton.on('click', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    var height = $('#book-container').height();
    if(height != 200){
        $('#book-container').height(200);
    }
    else{
        $('#book-container').height(100);
    }
});
```

I am wrapping the whole thing in the anchor tag `<a>` because I am crafting a search result item.

Regardless of adding `event.stopPropogation();` the click event on the `<a>` still fires.

Comment: can you share a sample of generated html

Comment: where are you appending `$expandBooksbutton`. Show the rendered HTML

Comment: http://jsbin.com/miqisaji/1/

Comment: var $divMoreBooks = $("<div id='show-more-books' class='pull-right'></div>");
                $divMoreBooks.append($expandBooksbutton);
                var $listdivs = $("<div id='book-container' style='height: 100px'></div>");
                $listdivs.append($divMoreBooks);
                $listdivs.append($booklist);
                $result.append($listdivs);

Comment: Why are you wrapping all your content in an anchor?

Comment: Its a search result, hence i need to append the contents.

Comment: @Joesoc—add it to your question, not in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between preventing bubbling and cancelling out the default browser behaviour. Try adding

```
return false;
```

in the end of your handler function, like this

```
    $expandBooksbutton.on('click', function(event){
    var height = $('#book-container').height();
    if(height != 200){
        $('#book-container').height(200);
    }
    else{
        $('#book-container').height(100);
    }
    return false;

});
```

This should be the solution if I understood the question correctly.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I should have mentioned that there's also an alternative for this (which actually I should have given as an advice primarily) and this is:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

This function actually prevents the default behaviour, whereas

> return false;

does both (stops bubbling & prevents default behaviour)

There's more info on this here: 
[event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
$(<a tag selector>).on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your full DOM structure, this will be slightly abstract. However event handlers bound to an element before it is added to the DOM aren't actually triggered.

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events):

> **Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on()**. 
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page...attach event handlers after the new HTML is placed into the page. Or, use delegated events....

So basically you have two options:
Create a handler for a delegated event and bind that to the parent element *after the parent is added to the DOM*. Note that this approach requires that the parent be nested inside the `<a>` as well.

```
$(parent-elem).on('click', '#btn-showMoreBooks', function(e) {
    // your handler logic
});
```

Of course, you can always keep your logic as-is, but bind the handler to the element only after it's added to the DOM. This is reasonable as long as you won't be re-creating that element dynamically more than once after the initial page load.